# Aggregate functions in where clause MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have multiples tables with Names and Ages like this:

```
| Name     | Age |
------------------
| Carlos   | 25  |
| Mauricio | 28  |
| Cesar    | 19  |
| Hernan   | 7   |
```

And I need to retrieve all the names that are above the average Age.
I tried

```
 select Name from Table1 where Age > avg(Age)
```

but I found that the where clause does not work with aggregate functions, so I tried

```
 select Name from Table 1 having Age > avg(Age)
```

But it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with following query:

```
select Name from Table1 where Age > (select avg(Age) from Table1)
```